# Bind events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the code below, why does `$("#sidenav-overlay").trigger("click")` work while `this.$sideNavOverlay.trigger("click")` doesn't work?

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {

    var app = {

      init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
      },
      cacheDom: function() {
        this.$buttonCollapse = $('.button-collapse');
        this.$sideNavClear = $("#side-nav-clear");
        this.$sideNavOverlay = $("#sidenav-overlay");
      },
      bindEvents: function() {
        this.$buttonCollapse.sideNav();
        this.$sideNavClear.on('click', this.closeSideNavigation.bind(this));
      },
      closeSideNavigation: function() {
        console.log('closesideNavigation');
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.$sideNavOverlay);
        console.log($("#sidenav-overlay"));
        //$("#sidenav-overlay").trigger("click");
        this.$sideNavOverlay.trigger("click");
      }

    };

    app.init();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

```css
.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://materializecss.com/css/ghpages-materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

<nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a>  <a class="right" id="side-nav-clear" style="margin-top: 22px;"><i class="material-icons small icon-demo">clear</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Scripts-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js"></script>
```

Comment: `this.$sideNavOverlay === $("#sidenav-overlay")` ?     `console.log(this.$sideNavOverlay);`
`console.log($("#sidenav-overlay"));`  are they the same ?

Comment: @passion: Where do you see that? I don't (and it wouldn't work, `$()` always returns a new object, so that condition will always be false).

Comment: @passion those two can never be equal

Comment: The logical conclusion is that something is removing the old `#sidenav-overlay` and then appending a *new* `#sidenav-overlay`.

Comment: SO snippet? JsFiddle? anything?

Comment: Preferably Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button), so the example is **runnable** on-site.

Comment: Can you atleast provide jsfiddle for example

Comment: where is your #sidenav-overlay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would account for the reported symptom is that something in code you haven't shown is removing the old `#sidenav-overlay` (the one you cached in your property) and then appending a *new* `#sidenav-overlay` instead. So you're triggering the event on the old, no-longer-in-the-page element instead of the new one.

And in fact, that's what's happening, and we can see by checking to see if the `#sidenav-overlay` you've saved is the same element that's in the DOM later when clicked (it isn't):

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {

    var app = {

      init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
      },
      cacheDom: function() {
        this.$buttonCollapse = $('.button-collapse');
        this.$sideNavClear = $("#side-nav-clear");
        this.$sideNavOverlay = $("#sidenav-overlay");
      },
      bindEvents: function() {
        this.$buttonCollapse.sideNav();
        this.$sideNavClear.on('click', this.closeSideNavigation.bind(this));
      },
      closeSideNavigation: function() {
        console.log(
          "Same element? " +
            ($("#sidenav-overlay")[0] === this.$sideNavOverlay[0])
        );
        $("#sidenav-overlay").trigger("click");
      }

    };

    app.init();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

```css
.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://materializecss.com/css/ghpages-materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

<nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a>  <a class="right" id="side-nav-clear" style="margin-top: 22px;"><i class="material-icons small icon-demo">clear</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Scripts-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js"></script>
```

So unless you can prevent whatever's removing and replacing the element from doing so, just look it up when you need it. (In general, unless you have a good reason for doing something else, looking up elements when you need them is preferable to keeping them in properties or variables.)

Comment: You might be correct on that but in my opinion I think your theory is incorrect. Please see my update post.

Comment: how can someone be correct and incorrect at the same time?

Comment: Its only my opinion that your wrong because, I did not remove or modify $sidenav-overlay but since I don't know what materialize did on that, that's why I say you might be correct.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez: Well, it's really easy to tell: Put an attribute or jQuery data property on it when you save it to your `this.$sideNavOverlay` property, and then look to see if it still has that attribute or data property later when the click occurs. Or save a reference to the actual DOM element (`this.$sideNavOverlay[0]`) and see if it's still the same one when the click occurs. I suspect it won't be.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez: And if I do that with your snippet, it confirms that they're different elements, so yes, I'm correct above that something is removing the old one and putting in a new one.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder thanks for your answer, It gives me some clarification